# Loading modules from folders

Tags: lua, love2d

My project structure is following:

```
--Shooter
----sprites
------background.png
------player.png
------zombie.png
----units
------player.lua
------zombie.lua
----main.lua
----load.lua
----update.lua
----draw.lua
```

And my `main.lua` will have the following:

```
local Bullet = require("units.bullet")
local Player = require("units.player")
local Zombie = require("units.zombie")

require("load")
require("update")
require("draw")
require("functions")

love.window.setTitle("Shooter")

function love.load()
    Load()
end

function love.update(dt)
    Update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    Draw()
end
```

For example, `bullet.lua`:

```
local Bullet =  {}
bulletSprite = love.graphics.newImage('sprites/bullet.png')

function Bullet.create()
    local newBullet = {
        pos = {},
        speed = 10,
        sprite = bulletSprite,
        direction = 0,
        dead = false
    }
    return setmetatable(newBullet, {__index = Bullet})
end

function Bullet:setPos(x, y)
    self.pos.x = x
    self.pos.y = y
end

function Bullet:setDirection(angle)
    self.direction = angle
end

function Bullet:move(dt)
    local distance = self.speed * dt * 60  
    self.pos.x = self.pos.x + math.cos(self.direction) * distance
    self.pos.y = self.pos.y + math.sin(self.direction) * distance
end


function spawnBullet(bullets, player)
    local newBullet = Bullet.create()
    newBullet:setPos(player.pos.x, player.pos.y)
    newBullet.direction = player.angle

    table.insert(bullets, newBullet)
end
```

The problem is that none of the files in `units` folder will load properly. From the error log I can see that it tries to search for `bullet.lua` in the root directory and then various `love2d` and `lua` libraries.

I have tried various things like `require("./units/bullet")` or replace `/` with `.` but so far, no luck.

Extracting those files from the `units` folder into root folder will work. Loading images from `sprites` folder works, however (for example `love.graphics.draw(sprites.background, 0, 0)`).

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem was that while my `main.lua` had correct `require`s, my `update` file didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind.

1. Make Sure LUA_PATH is set to your project directory
2. add `return Bullet`, `return Player` and so on... into each module you have created

Comment: 1. Isn't `LUA_PATH` global? Why would I add project-specific directories to a global? 2. I have returns in each module.